# Is this particular question primarily opinion based?

Tags: discussion, question-quality, specific-question, close-reasons

I'm asking about [this question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/718/which-tasks-on-an-open-source-project-tend-to-be-most-often-overlooked), which asks for examples where in hindsight a project would have done better if they had avoided overlooking an area of expertise.

I would expect answers to provide evidence (as requested) and therefore not be opinion based. Although the choice of evidence to present means this can never be purely objective, I would not want to see "purely objective" as a requirement for asking. This would require closing most of the existing questions.

I'd like to see discussion on this particular question: both whether it is primarily opinion based, and any ways it can be improved.

Answer (score 3):

I voted to close as *too broad*.

I don't this this question is too opinion-based. It is to some extent, but it's rather towards the kind of [“constructive subjective”](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) questions that work fine — inspiring answers that explain why and how, inviting answers sharing experiences over opinions, more than just mindless social fun.

But it is far too broad. It covers all types of projects, all kinds of aspects. It's an invitation for everyone to come and say what project X missed.

A reasonably-scoped question on this topic would be “I've done this and that for my project, my goal is this, what am I missing?”. Or “how can I evaluate whether I've done this part properly”.